# Displaying a DatePicker with or without the year field

Tags: android, datepicker

I would like to display a `DatePicker` where the year field would be visible or not, according to a checkbox.

But I didn't find anything giving me a way to implement it.

Any idea please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know thats not possible at least in Android sdk 1.5

Comment: I think you will waste less time by coding a DatePicker yourself that fits all your needs.

Comment: It's a slightly tricky requirement given that the dates that would be available varies depending on the year... The advice to consider writing your own version (at least for the year-not-visible version) is probably good.

Comment: @Casidiablo: Writing your own DatePicker is a lot more difficult than you make it sound.  Not only do you have to deal with different Calendar issues (leap years for example), the NumberPicker widget that is used is a private API.

Comment: Why NumberPicker is private, it's a shame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not possible to remove the year field from a `DatePicker`, I finally decide to add a `CheckBox` "ignore the year field" in order to implement a solution.

Answer (score 2):

set the check box listener as your need to view of checkbox

```
if(id == R.id.event_checkBox_year)
    {
        if(ch.isChecked())
        {
            visiblity = View.GONE;
        }
        else
        {
            visiblity = View.VISIBLE;
        }
        showHideYear(visiblity);
    }

 private void showHideYear(int visiblity)
 {
     try {
            Field f[] = date.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : f) {
                if (field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner") ||field.getName().equals("mYearPicker") ) 
                {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object yearPicker = new Object();
                    yearPicker = field.get(date);
                    ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(visiblity);
                }
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) 
        {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for not showing year spinner or year picker on date picker dialog

```
try {

       Field f[] = datePickerDialog.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object datePicker=new Object();
                datePicker=field.get(datePickerDialog);
                Field[] fields=datePicker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for(Field field1:fields){
                    if(field1.getName().equals("mYearSpinner") || field1.getName().equals("mYearPicker")){
                        field1.setAccessible(true);
                        Object ye=field1.get(datePicker);
                        ((View)ye).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
getDatePicker().findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```